# What does this kind of linear transformation mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a mapping from $T=(a, b, a+b):\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where both $a$ and $b$ are also mappings from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. What does the part $(a, b, a+b):\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ imply actually? Can I rewrite it as 
$$(a, b, a+b) \circ (x, y, z) = (j, k, l) $$ 
and
$$a(x) = j \quad b(y) = k \quad (a+b)(z) = l $$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T=(a,b,a+b)$ should mean that we define the map $T$ such that
$$T(x,y,z) = (a(x,y,z,), b(x,y,z),a(x,y,z)+b(x,y,z))$$
and since $a$ and $b$ are mappings from $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ this is well defined. Your sugestion that $a(x)=j$ etc. does not really make sence (although it is somewhat in the spirit of what I am saying), since this would imply that $(x,y,z)$ would be from $\mathbb{R^{3\times3}}$, or else, $a(x),b(y)$ and $(a+b)(z) $ are not well defined.

Comment: Thanks, so I have another linear mapping inside.